# Using Minimax Theorem of prove the determinacy of closed games?

Tags: general-topology, optimization, descriptive-set-theory

In this [paper](http://www.ratio.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/publications/dp524.pdf), page 6, Itai Arieli and Yehuda Levy mention briefly using using Minimax Theorem of prove the determinacy of closed game in a more general setting.

[image]

The minimax theorem they  mentioned can be founded [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/39/1/42.full.pdf):

[image]

I can't understand why this is true.
It seems to me  with respect to payoff function $f: X \times Y \to [0,1]$, $X$ and $Y$ are two players'  pure strategy space, which are subsets of $2^{A^{\omega}}$. What's the topology defined on pure strategy space to talk about Hausdorff condition, compactness, and semicontinuity?

**Added:** I found some clue in a cited paper by  Eran Shmaya(see page 7-8 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2254.pdf)).The pure stategy space is indeed compact, since it's a product of finite function spaces. But the definition of a game has a value is kind of weird to me, since it seems to me it can't be matched to Ky Fan's theorem.

[image]

In particular, I can't see why there's need to introduce mixed strategy space.

Answer (score 0):

The compactness of mixed strategy space, as the space of all measures of pure strategy space, is implied by compactness of pure strategy space, which is a product of finite function spaces. Mixed strategy guarentees that payoff function is affine in variables, which matches conditions in the Ky Fan's theorem that $f$ is convex and concave in two varibles respectively. To show the *l.s.c.* of the original payoff function, it suffices to  show the restriction of payoff function is *l.s.c.* with respect to player I's pure strategy space, given any player II's pure strategy, which is surely *l.s.c.*, given closed winning set.